# color strip or picture unfolding from one side to another in video editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Here is the issue with the video editor:
The effect i am trying to achieve is by using color strips:
1st thing displayed, a color strip (green) covering all screen:
Green Green Green Green Green Green
Green Green Green Green Green Green
Green Green Green Green Green Green
Green Green Green Green Green Green

Than a red strip appears in the scene, unfolding from left to right:
Moment 2:
Green Green Green Green Green Green
Green RED    Green Green Green Green
Green Green Green Green Green Green
Green Green Green Green Green Green

Moment 2:
Green Green Green Green Green Green
Green RED    RED     Green Green Green
Green Green Green Green Green Green
Green Green Green Green Green Green

Moment 3:
Green Green Green Green Green Green
Green RED     RED      RED     Green Green
Green Green Green Green Green Green
Green Green Green Green Green Green

Moment 4:
Green Green Green Green Green Green
Green RED     RED      RED     RED      Green
Green Green Green Green Green Green
Green Green Green Green Green Green

I did not find this kind of effect built in among transition effects in Blender..

How to get it right?

Comment: Related Animation Nodes add-on https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123883/animation-nodes-how-to-create-transition-with-the-gif-animated-squares

Comment: Can you please create answer as suggested by susu to let us know how you achieve that? Or extend your question about your blend to see what did you tried already. Link to your file from deleted answer is not accesible anymore.  I'm couriousse what was your goal. It is not still clear to me. Thank you ... I see now you asked two weeks ago ... hm.

Answer (score 2):

### Step 1 - Transition

If you mean something like flipping cards transition - Video Sequencer doesn't have this kind of transitions. You would have to render this kind of transition as black and white animation (or image sequence) and use as a mask in video editor.

If you need to keep 3D effect of rotated parts of images you will have to create material for Front/Back side and in 3D editor.

### ... with Animation Nodes

To create transition like this you can try to use **Animation Nodes** add-on to create a node tree like here:

[image]

[image]
Node-tree for 2.92

[image]

[Step by step tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q1lY6VXBQ_E) is a bit outdated, but it is well explaned.

### ... with Constraints

Another option can be to use Object Constraints with a help of [BlenderSushi script](https://blendersushi.blogspot.com/2013/05/python-advanced-procedural-flipping.html) for Blender 2.79 to handle tedious tasks.

- Add a *Grid* mesh like 6x4 segments
- in *Edit* mode select all search for *Split Edges*
- Add another Grid mesh, but with -1 segment on each axis (here 5x3 segments) and **rename it to "Template"**
- Select first Grid and run script <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> from Script editor.
- Script will generate Empty object for each face with **Transformation Constraint** - target to Template transforming location to rotation.
- script should set also rotation Max 180°, that is not happening for me so just after script when all generated empties are selected go to Constraints tab and set value 180. WIth right click choose *Copy to Selected*.
- Now you can add Displace Modifier to Template mesh and set any texture to control flipping. Cloud type for random animation, Blend type Linear or Diagonal for transition from side to side.

[image]

[image]

---

### Step 2 - Video Sequencer

If you create some animation render this sequence in Black&White ...

[image]

- Add this animation (or image sequence) as a strip into Video Sequencer (you can even hide this strip)
- Add two images or colors strips you want to mix
- Select top one and under Strip Properties <kbd>N</kbd> > Modifiers tab > add **Mask modifier** and set your B&W transition strip.

[image]

If you are interest to go by this way I can extend answer  how to create a BW mask for Video editor or use a Scene strip, but you are probably looking to easier solution. SO try to search for already done some BW transition or you would have to use other app for that.

Or closer specificities behaviour of transition so there can be other solution for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer although you went too far.. What i wanted was much much simpler.. I pulled it by trial and error but i can not figure how to upload the blend file to this forum.. Please keep the answer, it's sure to be beneficial for somebody, and myself in the near future..

Comment: @FouadHoblos if you found a way to do it, please share it as an answer in the answers section, so that others can with a similar question can learn from your experience. Remember that this site is trying to create a knowledge base.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the technical means you tried, what goal do you want to achieve?
Do you want the red square to appear on top of the green strip? If yes you need only 2 strips and key frames on the opacity of the red strip (which can be cropped to a square in the strip itself)